# Not able to upload files in chrome incognito mode when tried with selenium 4 and SSO with ((HasAuthentication) driver).register

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to upload files in chrome browser with incognito mode. Application is with SSO and authentication is handled with selenium 4. The below code is used for authentication

```
((HasAuthentication) driver).register(UsernameAndPassword.of(username, password));
```

Normal mode able to upload files but in incognito mode getting error" 403 unauthorized-invalid WID"

Comment: Manually it works with SSO and incognito mode? Preferably on a different browser/new browser (Firefox i.e.) to prevent all traces to old iets.

Comment: Yes manually works fine and even when i use robot class for SSO it works fine. Issue is with authorization code used with selenium 4.

Comment: @TacoVerhagen did you get any solution for this issue?

Comment: Unfortunatly, no. An issue like this is on my 'TODO' list to implement myself, but other things have priority.